# Exactly simulate recursive algorithm into Iterative

Tags: algorithm, recursion, iteration

I was asked to exactly simulate a recursive algorithm with an iterative one. Exactly means that I have to simulate stack record that a real pc does during execution.
Assuming that I have a binary search tree that contains only a key and two references at his right and left child I want to do this count:

```
CountOddRec(T)
  ret = 0
  if T != NIL then
      if T->key % 2 = 1 then
          ret = T->key
      rsx = CountOddRec(T->sx);
      rdx = CountOddRec(T->dx);
      ret = ret + rsx + rdx;
  return ret
```

Basically my idea is to use the general scheme of iterative binary tree visit to do that:

```
VisitIter(T)
  last = NIL 
  curr = T
  stk = NULL
  while (curr != NIL || stk != NIL) do
      if curr != NIL then
          //Pre-order visit
          stk = push(stk, curr)
          next = curr->sx 
      else
          curr = Top(stk)

          if (last != curr-> dx) then
              //In-order visit

          if (last != curr-> dx  && curr->dx != NULL) then
              next  = curr->dx
          else
              //Post-order visit
              stk = pop(stk)
              next = NIL
      last = curr
      curr = next
```

Now I know that this one should be in Pre-order block:

```
      if T->key % 2 = 1 then
          ret = T->key
```

The `rsx =` assignment should be in-order, and `rdx =` assignment and last block should be in post-order.
Now here I'm stuck, I ask if someone could help me to understand how finish the algorithm.

**EDIT**
I've changed in-order visit as it was not correct, then this is my first attempt that should work:

```
CountOddIter(T)
  last = NIL 
  curr = T

  stk = NULL //stack
  Sret = NULL //stack
  Srsx = NULL //stack

  ret = 0

  while (curr != NIL || stk != NIL) do
      ret = 0
      if curr != NIL then
          //Pre-order block
          if (curr->key % 2 == 1) then
              ret = curr->key

          Sret = push(Sret, ret)

          stk = push(stk, curr)
          next = curr->sx 
      else
          curr = Top(stk)

          if (last != curr-> dx) then
              //In-order block
              Srsx = push(Srsx, pop(Sret))

          if (last != curr-> dx  && curr->dx != NULL) then
              next  = curr->dx
          else
              //Post-order block
              rdx = pop(Sret)
              rsx = pop(Srsx)
              r = pop(Sret)

              ret = rdx + rsx + r

              Sret = push(Sret, ret)

              stk = pop(stk)
              next = NIL
      last = curr
      curr = next
```

This works if I assume that a pop on an empty stack returns 0.
Any other suggestions? Improvements?

Comment: I generally solve this by allocating a stack in the heap and using it instead xD

Comment: What do you mean? I need to simulate exactly the recursion so for this reason I've used stack, is there any other method?